# How to execute a SQL query in Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to run the following code:

```
spark.sql('USE DATABASE test ;')
```

It gives me the error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: 
extraneous input 'test' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 1, pos 13)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Try ```spark.sql('USE test;')```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is - `USE <database_name>` as explained [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-usedb.html).

In general, Spark SQL syntax is documented [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax.html).